# Is there a way to select files path in jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want a file selector which gives me the path.Like a file selector selects the file path and upload the file.Is it possible that something like that gives me the real path of the entity?
Like i select a file abc.mp3 and i get its full path d:\xxxx\xxxx\abc.mp3.I dont know is it is possible or not is there something like this in jQuery?

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Comment: Simple answer, no.  Everything is designed so you don't get access to the file system.  More complex solutions (flash for example) might be able to do it, that I'm not sure of.  But with js and php, it *shouldn't* be possible

Comment: Cant we even read the directories present on the server?

Comment: The server or the client?  I was talking about the client, the server is another story entirely (and a lot easier).

Comment: I was talking about server.If there is something on server which can select the path.Like an application is installed on a system i need ability to select a path of that system like file upload control.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to use something like php or asp.net (languages that run on the server) to select files **on the server**?  You can't select files on the client's computer (the computer requesting the webpage), only on the server (the computer serving the webpage).

Comment: Yes i want something that could read a path of a file on my own system not any one elses.

Comment: Look at ajax, put in the url to the file, and it'll read it into a javascript variable, or you could use php and write the file into a javascript variable on page load, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the answer is no. For security, most browsers have adopted the policy to not allow the path to be available in JavaScript.

I am fairly certain some older browsers used to keep the entire path in the file field's value, but the policy that all current major browsers use is to only keep the filename without the file path.

Comment: IE only returns the file name, this should never be relied upon.